# Render table rows without binding for performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, dom-manipulation

I'm using Angular 1.4. It's commonly known that ng-repeat can have some performance issues when rendering a large number of rows for things like tables. But I was wondering if there was an optimal way of using ng-repeat or some alternative iteration to simply render an array of data I have, for a table.

I don't need any binding, as it's just outputting data for a report. I've tried some suggestions like one-time binding, but it still takes a good amount of time (10 seconds or more for 1000 records or so). Other non-Angular methods I've tried are pre-rendering the HTML on the backend, and then returning the HTML instead of the data array. And I had a custom directive that just added that HTML to the element. This was less than a second for even 2000 rows (obviously since I didn't use Angular).

But it would be nice if I could accomplish the same thing in Angular, or even do something similar in the controller on the Angular side. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why you'd want to render 1000 rows.

Comment: I would normally paginate it, but the users want to be able to see all the data at one time, or do a Ctrl + F to find a record they're looking for. So it's more of a business requirement. Although not too common, the report they run is based on a date range, so the number of records can be large if they pick a large time frame.

Comment: It it what it is then I guess. I would give [Use ng-repeat sparingly](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/1921/profiling-and-performance/6270/7-simple-performance-improvements#t=20170220203549826701) a look including "other approaches" other than paging. The truth is they likely cannot see them all, you just have to give them the perception they can and the other functionality you mentioned can still be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one-way binding for this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in ::items">
  <li>{{ ::item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Note that you have to add the `::` syntax to each entry in the repeater.

I'm not sure how complex your logic is, but 10 seconds for 1000 rows sounds absurd.